# hazelcast Cache locking issue on cluster env Current thread is not owner of the lock! -> <not-locked>

Tags: spring, multithreading, hibernate, jpa, hazelcast

Hi am getting a hazelcast lock issue in prod env ,am using spring+hibernate+hazelcast its a cluster wit 2 node.Current hazelcast version is 3.1.3

But am not able to reproduce in my local env.I have analysed the logs it sees after JPA transaction get complete its trying to release lock.

below are the logs:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:522)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor525.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.csam.wsc.security.message.replay.filter.MessageReplayDetectionFilter.doFilter(MessageReplayDetectionFilter.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:92)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:513)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Exception releasing cache locks
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$AfterTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.afterTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:791)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.afterTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:626)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterTransaction(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.afterTransactionCompletion(JdbcTransaction.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: Current thread is not owner of the lock! -> <not-locked>
    at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.UnlockOperation.run(UnlockOperation.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.OperationServiceImpl.doRunOperation(OperationServiceImpl.java:274)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.OperationServiceImpl.access$800(OperationServiceImpl.java:52)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.OperationServiceImpl$RemoteOperationProcessor.run(OperationServiceImpl.java:744)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.OperationServiceImpl$OperationThread.run(OperationServiceImpl.java:791)
    at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.resolveResponse(InvocationImpl.java:411)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.get(InvocationImpl.java:294)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.get(InvocationImpl.java:286)
    at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.proxy.LockProxySupport.unlock(LockProxySupport.java:150)
    at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxyImpl.unlock(MapProxyImpl.java:238)
    at com.hazelcast.hibernate.distributed.IMapRegionCache.unlock(IMapRegionCache.java:125)
    at com.hazelcast.hibernate.access.ReadWriteAccessDelegate.unlockItem(ReadWriteAccessDelegate.java:65)
    at com.hazelcast.hibernate.region.EntityRegionAccessStrategyAdapter.unlockItem(EntityRegionAccessStrategyAdapter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.doAfterTransactionCompletion(EntityUpdateAction.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$AfterTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.afterTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:784
```

can anyone help or give input.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did the cluster topology change shortly before this exception?

Comment: sorry I donot understand topology,but nothing has been changed on prod env. is it something which can be changed due to the above exception.Env has not been changed we restarted node one by one after this exception.could this issue be with hibernate transactional caching?

Comment: Hazelcast version 3.1.3 is very old. Can you try a newer version?

Comment: updated to 3.8 hazelcast and no such error since last 1 month thanks for the help